# Detect lightning:recordForm change in mode attribute

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura-attribute, lightning-record-form

I'm trying to disable some surrounding components based on the `mode` attribute within `lightning:recordForm` (i.e. anytime I'm in `edit` mode, I'd like to disable a `lightning:buttonMenu` that sits just outside the `lightning:recordForm`).

I'm using an aura attribute `v.formMode` to store the default mode "view", but it doesn't seem to update itself when I double click in the UI to make inline edits.

I looked through both [lightning:recordForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordForm/specification) and [lightning:recordEditForm](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:recordEditForm/specification) documentation, but there's no special event to catch when the mode is changing, and it doesn't seem to auto-update the binded aura variable.

```
<lightning:recordForm 
    aura:id="recordForm"
    recordId="{!v.recordId}"
    objectApiName="Case"
    fields="{!v.fields}"
    columns="2"
    mode="{! v.formMode }" />
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> `mode` on recordForm is 1-way binding. When the mode of `recordForm` changes, it does not automatically reflect in the parent component attribute binding. So we need to implement some logic to come around that limitation which is implemented in example below:

cmp:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:isUrlAddressable" access = "GLOBAL">

    <aura:attribute name="mode" type="String" default="view" />
    <aura:attribute name="showEditBtn" type="Boolean" default="true" />
    <aura:attribute name="initDone" type="Boolean" default="false" />

    <div class="slds-theme_default">
        <lightning:recordForm recordId="00128000009j45sAAA"
                              objectApiName="Account"
                              layoutType="Full"
                              onload="{!c.handleLoad}"
                              onsuccess="{!c.handleSuccess}"
                              columns="2"
                              mode="{#v.mode}"/>
        mode - {!v.mode}
    </div>

</aura:component>
```

1. Notice the 1-time binding `#` for mode. This is needed so that form does not go into infinite loop of edit and view when setting the mode in `onload`.
2. When recordForm is initialised, `onload` is triggered 2 times (before and after loading form), and so `mode` turns from view to edit and again back to view, so handler for this is not much required (only not to make it more complex).
3. Also on `onsuccess`, first `onload` fires which makes mode as edit, so we have to set it back to `view` on `handleSuccess` method.
4. After saving, if an error occurs because of validation rules, even then onload fires 2 times (Once immediately `onsubmit` when `Save` is clicked and 2nd time when it shows error - `onerror`). So again, mode will be changed back to edit mode, and hence no handler is required even in this case.

and its JS:

```
({
    handleLoad : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log("loaded record form");
        let mode = (component.get("v.mode")==='view') ? 'edit' : 'view';
        component.set("v.mode",mode);
    },
    handleSuccess : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.mode', 'view');
    }
})
```

**Note: I already pointed this behaviour of `mode` of `recordForm` in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/271848/lightning-component-to-display-standard-buttons/271851#271851). But I think nobody noticed.**

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation here - I learned a lot.  I think I'll have to revisit the original requirements as `mode` is not auto-updating itself

Comment: @BrianMiller. WC ). Pls mark as solved if solved

Comment: Keeping it open (i.e. not solved) just in case someone else has a better idea on how to achieve my original question - to disable surrounding components based on the UI change from view to edit mode

Answer (score 1):

Mode initialization works only once. After you manually change mode in `lightning:recordForm`, it doesn't fire neither component, nor application change event(tested in Salesforce Lightning Inspector).

You can handle changes of mode via `onload` handler.
But keep in mind, when component is rendering, it fires `onload` twice. That's why you need to skip first time `onload`.

Also, when you've successfully saved changes, it is additionally fires `onload`. So, `onsuccess` should set `formMode` to 'view'.

**Component**

```html
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId">
    <aura:attribute name="skipFirstLoad" type="Boolean" default="true"/>
    <aura:attribute name="formMode" type="String" default="view" access="private"/>

    <lightning:recordForm
            aura:id="recordForm"
            recordId="{!v.recordId}"
            objectApiName="Case"
            fields="{!v.fields}"
            columns="2"
            mode="{#v.formMode}"
            onload="{!c.loadHandler}"
            onsuccess="{!c.successHandler}"
    />
</aura:component>
```

**JS Controller**

```js
({
    loadHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        if(component.get('v.skipFirstLoad')) {
            component.set('v.skipFirstLoad', false);
            return;
        }
        component.set('v.formMode', component.get('v.formMode') === 'view' ? 'edit' : 'view');
    },

    successHandler : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set('v.formMode', 'view');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about the `onload` behavior and you confirmed my suspicions about `mode`